# Why can't I install nspluginwrapper?

Tags: apt, package-management, citrix

I'm trying to install nspluginwrapper using this from various tutorials I've found:

`sudo apt-get install -y nspluginwrapper`

But I get this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package nspluginwrapper
```

I tried to go to their website (http://nspluginwrapper.org/) and it seems down.  Does this not exist anymore?  I believe I need it in order to install a Citrix receiver.

I'm using 64 bit Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Latest version of [Citrix Receiver 13.10](https://www.citrix.com/downloads/citrix-receiver/linux/receiver-for-linux-latest.html) does not require Netscape Plugins.

Visit above page and then download Debian Package → Full Packages (Self-Service Support), the file named *`icaclient_13.10.0.20_amd64.deb`* will be placed in your `~/Downloads` folder. It may be installed on 18.04 LTS directly.
On Ubuntu 20.04 LTS you need to install it with dependencies using below commands:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/webkitgtk/libwebkitgtk-1.0-0_2.4.11-3ubuntu3_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/webkitgtk/libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0-0_2.4.11-3ubuntu3_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/icu/libicu60_60.2-3ubuntu3.2_amd64.deb

sudo apt-get install ./icaclient_13.10.0.20_amd64.deb ./libwebkitgtk-1.0-0_2.4.11-3ubuntu3_amd64.deb ./libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0-0_2.4.11-3ubuntu3_amd64.deb ./libicu60_60.2-3ubuntu3.2_amd64.deb
```

For modern installations Citrix recommends to use [Citrix Workspace](https://www.citrix.com/downloads/workspace-app/linux/workspace-app-for-linux-latest.html), it installs well on 20.04 LTS without wget commands.

Comment: Hi, that worked thanks!  How did you know that I needed to run the three `wget` lines?

Comment: I discovered this when tried to install Citrix Receiver on various Ubuntu versions. For 18.04 LTS wget commands are not needed. For 20.04 LTS they are needed. By using these 3 commands we satisfy the dependencies which do not exist in 20.04 LTS version. Also I should note that Citrix recommends to use [Citrix Workspace](https://www.citrix.com/downloads/workspace-app/linux/workspace-app-for-linux-latest.html) on modern installations, it installs well without wget commands.

Comment: oh wow, thanks for trying it on different versions.  Did you know about those three dependencies just looking at an error message that pops up when you tried to install it?  Or did you do a compare and contrast of some sort to find the three?  Just trying to figure out how to be a better ubuntu/linux user

Comment: At first I tried `sudo apt-get install ./icaclient_13.10.0.20_amd64.deb`, then it complain about missed 3 packages. So I went to https://packages.ubuntu.com for search to determine download links of these packages for previous Ubuntu releases. Such method is needed only when packages are missed in official repositories.